# microsoft azure - get directory full path

Tags: c#, azure, directory

I'm using microsoft azure websites.
I've saved files in the FTP hosting outside the wwwroot directory (for security issues)
when I try to use the following code **in my localhost it works fine**
****but when I upload the code to azure servers the result is:
"d:\windows\data"****

my way to get the directory is:

```
      string path = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath("../data/");
```

how can I find the full path using **Azure** websites? (again - it works in the localhost)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use `Sever.MapPath("../data/")` to get the physical path.